# Can't understand Java doubly linked list

Tags: java, data-structures, doubly-linked-list

I have this code

```
public class Doublylinkedlist {
    private DLLNode head;
    private DLLNode tail;
    private int length;
}
```

What is this `DLLNode` head declaration? What data type it is? Can someone please explain?

Here is the DLLNode class

```
Public class DLLNode{
private int data ;
private DLLNode prev;
private DLLNode next;
```

}

Now what is this 'private DLLNode prev'?
What data type it is ?

Comment: DLLNode is not a standard class. It's something you're supposed to define  yourself, or it's been provided to you

Comment: `DLLNode` stands for Doubly Linked List Node. I assume it represents.. a node in the doubly linked list.

Comment: Are the classes `DoublyLinkedList` and `DLLNode` part of a library provided by your teacher?  Clearly `DLLNode` is a class that holds a reference to one object contained in the list, plus forward and backwards references to other `DLLNodes`. But these are not standard Java classes, so we don't really know what they are.  You need to tell us where you got them.

Comment: The data type of `DLLNode` is `DLLNode`. It's  a class that you write yourself that contains the data as well as 2 references (1 to previous element and 1 to next element)

Comment: a single linked list means, that every element knows the next one. A -> B -> C. You can iterate through it from start to end. A doubly linked list simply means that every element knows the next one and the one before itself. A <-> B <-> C. So you can iterate through it from both directions. head is simply a reference to the before element, tail to the next. Guessing here, but head being null would mean you are at the start (no element before this one) and tail being null would mean that you are at the end (no next element).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DLLNode is a user defined class just like your Doublylinkedlist class.

A possible example of what that DLLNode class might look like:

```
public class DLLNode
{
    int data;
    DLLNode next;
    DLLNode prev;

    public DLLNode(int data)
    {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = null;
        this.prev = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is this DLLNode next ??

Comment: Nope :) it is missing a `DLLNode previous;`

Comment: @IndraneelMukherjee it is a reference to the next node in the list.

Comment: A linked list is just a bunch of nodes chained together. A->B->C->D. In this case a node holds some data of type int named "data" and a reference to the next node in the list refereed to as "next". A node needs to hold a reference to the next node in the list otherwise you would have no way to traverse the list.

Comment: What i cant understand is what is this 'DLLNode next ' inside that DLLNode class.

Comment: What type of data type is DLLnode next ?

Comment: next is of type DLLNode. It's a little weird, but it makes sense since next has to refer to the next node in the list.