# Inner class in java in doubly linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

```
public class DLLNode{
    private int data;
    private DLLNode prev;
    private DLLNode next;
}
```

What is this `private DLLNode prev`?

How a class can be defined inside of a class?

Comment: This is now the second time you ask a question with the same code snippet. You obviously have a very poor knowledge of Java's basics. Please, go and read some [tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) first.

Comment: The duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35533868/cant-understand-java-doubly-linked-list .

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose yes,i hv just started :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not defining a class, it's defining a field within the class of type `DLLNode`.

The code you supplied basically defines a class of type `DLLNode` with 3 private fields:

- A field of type `integer`, referred to as `data`.
- A field of type `DLLNode`, referred to as `prev`.
- A field of type `DLLNode`, referred to as `next`.

All this means is that once a `DLLNode` object will be created, it will contain 3 values - 1 integer value and 2 address values, where the `DLLNode` fields are kept.

This basically enables you to reference the object, even if it is inside the same "definition". i.e. the following code is legal:

```
public class DLLNode{

    private int data;
    private DLLNode prev;
    private DLLNode next;

    public int whatsNext() {
        return next.data; // btw, a null check if always encouraged :)
    }
}
```

All I've done here, in `whatsNext` method, was reference the `next` field and access its `data` field. Basically, I just asked Java for an address where an object of type `DLLNode` is kept (`next`), and then accessed one of its fields, as if it were any other objects.

Again, the key idea here is that this is defining a simple field as any other, not redefining the class itself.

Comment: Well explained .thanks :)

Comment: Happy to help. Could you I ask you to return the favor and accept my answer? Thanks.